# Where can I find the symfony 2.7 route for the web directory (the index file)

Tags: symfony, directory

I recently started using Symfony and I want to edit the index page at the

```
http://localhost/my_project/web/
```

directory, but I cant find the Sprigs route for it. Also I don't have a index.? file in the web directory.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Symfony doesn't use `index.php` file as entry point. It uses `app.php` and `app_dev.php` as entry points for accordingly production and development environment.

For fresh Symfony installation, homepage route points to `DefaultController:indexAction` which you can find in `src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController`.

Also as you will find in this controller, this action uses `default/index.html.twig` template which you can find in `app/Resources/views/` directory.

For more information please check Symfony Book and Cookbook, which you can find [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html). Especially you should go through the Book to get familiar with Symfony concepts.